# sql - IN, JOIN or EXISTS for filtering

Tags: sql, inner-join, exists, sql-in

I have the following two entities:

```
project(identifier, name, ...)
member(identifier, name, ...)
```

They are joined by the following table:

```
project-member(project_identifier, member_identifier)
```

What is the most common way to find out which projects a certain member (by identifier) belongs to? I see three possibilities:

```
select r1.*
from   project r1
join   project-member r2
       on r2.member_identifier = 3 and r1.identifier = r2.project_identifier;

select *
from   project r1
where  r1.identifier in (select project_identifier from project-member where member_identifier = 3);

select *
from   project r1
where  exists (select * from project-member where member_identifier = 3 and project_identifier = r1.identifier);
```

I understand that it mostly depends on the data and that the query plan should be analyzed with real-life data, but I want to know what the default choice would be. I expect it is the `EXISTS` construction, but I would like to have your opinion.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692992/join-versus-exists-performance, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227037/can-i-get-better-performance-using-a-join-or-using-exists, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001543/in-vs-join-with-large-rowsets and many many others

Comment: Each has pros and cons to their use.  Personally I try and use joins as it never seems to fail that I'll need data from the  other table. tables at some point.  If I know for certain I'll not need such data, then I generally use exists.  I default to IN usually when I have a set already defined and can pass it in as a variable.  but there's always exceptions and context generally matters.  do I need best performance, simplest to maintain, or potential to scale? All 3 are common. Evaluating performance exists is likely the fastest; assuming appropriate indexes. But you asked for COMMON;so all 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say it depends on many factors that are not stated in the question, but assuming correct indexes are in place I believe they will produce the same or at least very similar query plans since they all begin by fetching a specific set of rows from project-member and then joins that against project.

I think this variant seems most natural:

```
select p.*
from project-member pm
inner join project p on p.identifier = pm.project_identifier
where pm.member_identifier = 3
```

That is, filter rows from a table based on what you have a predicate for, and then join the other table to get the information you actually need.